# #2014 - Commands out of sync. you can't run this command now. Query was working before. But now it is not working

Tags: mysql

My table structure is ... There is Counter which has many Box in it. Box has a one BoxType. and Collection stores Box datewise revenue and data. I need data of particular 1 COUNTER (Data of All the box belongs to it.) .

counter table

[image: Counter Table Data structure]

box table

[image: Box atble data structure]

box_type table
[image: box_type table data structure]

Collection table
[image: collection table data structure]

The query returns data on some data.
[image: Query returns data on previous db with same structure less data.]

Query not working on new inserted data. **It ssays : #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now and 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`bt`.`end_val`-`bt`.`start_val`)'**

[image: **It ssays : #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now and 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(<code>cdcblog_lottery_scanner</code>.<code>bt</code>.<code>end_val</code> - <code>cdcblog_lottery_scanner</code>.<code>bt</code>.<code>start_val</code>)'**]

Here is my query...  **was working before now with new data having problem**

```html
SELECT `b`.`box_id`,
       `bt`.`box_type_id`,
       `bt`.`price`,
       `bt`.`start_val`,
       `bt`.`end_val`,
       ((`bt`.`end_val` - `bt`.`start_val`) + 1) AS totalTickets,
       (CASE
           WHEN (SELECT SUM(`co1`.`sold_tickets`)
                   FROM `collections` `co1`
                        INNER JOIN `boxes` `b1`
                           ON     `b1`.`box_id` = `co1`.`box_id`
                              AND `b1`.`status` = "1"
                        INNER JOIN `counters` `c1`
                           ON     `c1`.`counter_id` = `b1`.`counter_id`
                              AND `c1`.`status` = "1"
                        INNER JOIN `box_types` `bt1`
                           ON     `bt1`.`box_type_id` = `b1`.`box_type_id`
                              AND `bt1`.`status` = "1"
                  WHERE `co1`.`status` = "1" AND `b1`.`box_id` = `b`.`box_id`)
                   IS NULL
           THEN
              0
           ELSE
              (SELECT SUM(`co1`.`sold_tickets`)
                 FROM `collections` `co1`
                      INNER JOIN `boxes` `b1`
                         ON     `b1`.`box_id` = `co1`.`box_id`
                            AND `b1`.`status` = "1"
                      INNER JOIN `counters` `c1`
                         ON     `c1`.`counter_id` = `b1`.`counter_id`
                            AND `c1`.`status` = "1"
                      INNER JOIN `box_types` `bt1`
                         ON     `bt1`.`box_type_id` = `b1`.`box_type_id`
                            AND `bt1`.`status` = "1"
                WHERE `co1`.`status` = "1" AND `b1`.`box_id` = `b`.`box_id`)
        END)
          AS soldTickets,
       (  ((`bt`.`end_val` - `bt`.`start_val`) + 1)
        - (CASE
              WHEN (SELECT SUM(`co1`.`sold_tickets`)
                      FROM `collections` `co1`
                           INNER JOIN `boxes` `b1`
                              ON     `b1`.`box_id` = `co1`.`box_id`
                                 AND `b1`.`status` = "1"
                           INNER JOIN `counters` `c1`
                              ON     `c1`.`counter_id` = `b1`.`counter_id`
                                 AND `c1`.`status` = "1"
                           INNER JOIN `box_types` `bt1`
                              ON     `bt1`.`box_type_id` = `b1`.`box_type_id`
                                 AND `bt1`.`status` = "1"
                     WHERE     `co1`.`status` = "1"
                           AND `b1`.`box_id` = `b`.`box_id`)
                      IS NULL
              THEN
                 0
              ELSE
                 (SELECT SUM(`co1`.`sold_tickets`)
                    FROM `collections` `co1`
                         INNER JOIN `boxes` `b1`
                            ON     `b1`.`box_id` = `co1`.`box_id`
                               AND `b1`.`status` = "1"
                         INNER JOIN `counters` `c1`
                            ON     `c1`.`counter_id` = `b1`.`counter_id`
                               AND `c1`.`status` = "1"
                         INNER JOIN `box_types` `bt1`
                            ON     `bt1`.`box_type_id` = `b1`.`box_type_id`
                               AND `bt1`.`status` = "1"
                   WHERE     `co1`.`status` = "1"
                         AND `b1`.`box_id` = `b`.`box_id`)
           END))
          AS remainingTickets
  FROM `collections` `co`
       INNER JOIN `boxes` `b`
          ON `b`.`box_id` = `co`.`box_id` AND `b`.`status` = "1"
       INNER JOIN `counters` `c`
          ON `c`.`counter_id` = `b`.`counter_id` AND `c`.`status` = "1"
       INNER JOIN `box_types` `bt`
          ON `bt`.`box_type_id` = `b`.`box_type_id` AND `bt`.`status` = "1"
 WHERE `co`.`status` = "1" AND `b`.`counter_id` = "1"
GROUP BY `b`.`box_id`
ORDER BY `b`.`box_id` ASC
```

**How do i improve this query for consistent performance and is there a better way of doing this thing.**

Answer (score 0):

FInnaly solved the problem thanks to @verace on dba forum.

I don't think the problem is with your query, but rather with your data. Check out the error message

> It ssays : #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command
>   now and 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in
>   '(bt.end_val-bt.start_val)'

I think for some reason, now (bad data entry?), your query is trying to insert a negative value into an UNSIGNED INT which is not allowed.

[EDIT]

I found it strange that you couldn't subract one integer from another so I tested with a sample data set.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `test1` (
    ->   `start_val` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `end_val` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.50 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 values(3, 4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 values(4, 3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
```

So, two simple records in a simple table.

Then I ran this very simple query:

```
mysql> select end_val - start_val from test1;
```

and *INCREDIBLY* I got the result:

```
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`test`.`test1`.`end_val` - `test`.`test1`.`start_val`)
```

I investigated and found that there is a setting

> [NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_unsigned_subtraction)
>
> By default, subtraction between integer operands produces an UNSIGNED
>   result if any operand isUNSIGNED.

This has to be switched off if you with to subtract UNSIGNED INT values. I consider this to be a bug in MySQL - all the more egregious since there are no CHECK constraints in MySQL - but one could have plenty of reasons to wish to subtract two positve integers and obtain a negative result (debts, whatnot), but you can't do that in MySQL. Absolutely incredible! Unsigned INTs should not be used for anything but PRIMARY KEYs.

**It is because in my data structure ... start_val and end_val are UNSIGNED attribute.. so they and the parent ('(bt.end_val-bt.start_val)') made out of them should be a UNSIGNED ... but because of wrong data insertions it was in minus. which is causing the problem.**